# how to use a variable in a loDash function

Tags: javascript, lodash

Good day,

here is my data schema:

the length of data can change depending on a query

```
var data = {
IP1: 1,2,3,4,5,6
IP2: 4,5,6,7,8,9
IP3: 1,7,8,5,9,6,3}

keys=Object.keys(data)

sum=[]
for (i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
k='o.'+keys[i]

sum.push(_.sumBy(data, function(o) { return k }))
}
```

I am working on Skywise/palantir at some point I need to sum all columns, using loDash `sumBy` function

My question : is there a method to have o.key[i] as a variable in the lodash function?

Thanks for your help.

Regards

Comment: Your question isn't very clear right now. Like @ShahadatHossain mentioned, first start by:

- Describing the object you want to manipulate
- Then describe what you want to achieve.

This does 2 things:
- Provides context and visibility into what your data is
- Allows people to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: I am expecting sample data that dataSys variable contains.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to get the sums of the columns (1, 4, 1 for example).

You can use lodash to create a function with `_.flow()`, that takes the values of the object (the arrays), transposes them (rows to columns) using `_.unzip()`, and then sums each column by mapping it with `_.sum()`:

```js
const { flow, values, unzip, map, sum } = _ 

const fn = flow(
  values, // get the values of the object - a list of arrays 
  unzip, // unzip to transpose the arrays to columns
  arrs => map(arrs, sum) // sum each column
)

const data = {
  IP1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  IP2: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  IP3: [1, 7, 8, 5, 9, 6, 3]
}

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

And the slightly cleaner lodash/fp version:

```js
const { flow, values, unzip, map, sum } = _ 

const fn = flow(
  values, // get the values of the object - a list of arrays 
  unzip, // unzip to transpose the arrays to columns
  map(sum) // sum each column
)

const data = {
  IP1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  IP2: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  IP3: [1, 7, 8, 5, 9, 6, 3]
}

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```